# grpc/c++ Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: c++, ssl, client, grpc

I am creating a static library out of my grpc c++ client and I am able to successfully call the API in the grpc static library using a test application.

But when I integrate the static library with a different service and call the API in the grpc static lib from that service, it fails with the error below

*Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.*
*Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xx'*
*Failed to create channel args during subchannel creation.*

On the same VM where I see the above error when I copy and run the test application that calls the grpc client, it works fine.

Here is the client code, based on(https://www.programmersought.com/article/7290364277/):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    grpc::SslCredentialsOptions ssl_options;
    ssl_options.pem_root_certs = SERVER_CRT;
    // Create a default SSL ChannelCredentials object.
    auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(ssl_options);
    grpc::ChannelArguments cargs;
    cargs.SetSslTargetNameOverride("xxx.xxx.com"); // If you add DNS, you don't need this.

    // Create a channel using the credentials created in the previous step.
    auto channel = grpc::CreateCustomChannel("1.2.3.4:8000", channel_creds , cargs);

    // Instantiate the client.
    MailClient tester(channel);

}
    
ssl_options.pem_root_certs = SERVER_CRT;

// The contents of server.crt
const char SERVER_CRT[] = R"(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TjERMA8GA1UECAwIU2hhbmdoYWkxEjAQBgNVBAcMCVNvbmdqaWFuZzEPMA0GA1UE
...
E6v50RCQgtWGmna+oy1I2UTVABdjBFnyKPEuz106mBfOhT6cg80hBHVgrV7sLHq8
76QolJm8yzZPL1qpiO4dKHHsCP6R
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)";
```

Probably some issue with the way I have provided the cert?

why does the rpc call in the grpc client work from the test application but not from a different service
on the same VM?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `I0408 08:38:10.927269051    4989 ssl_transport_security.cc:908] Invalid nullptr argument to |tsi_set_min_and_max_tls_versions|.
E0408 08:38:10.927316013    4989 ssl_security_connector.cc:116] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0408 08:38:10.927351125    4989 secure_channel_create.cc:107] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'securerelayserver.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8888`               


ssl_context is null, why would that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application that I was trying to integrate was using libssl 1.0.2 which doesn't support TLS1.3 but grpc 1.35 by default uses TLS1.3 and openssl 1.1.1. So built gRPC with gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package and it picked up libssl 1.0.2 and that fixed the issue. Hope this helps anyone.